# How to convert a Date string to a DateTime object?

Tags: python, datetime

I have following date:

```
2005-08-11T16:34:33Z
```

I need to know if this is date is before or after *datetime(2009,04,01)* and I can't seem to find a method that will convert that string to something that lets me compare it to *datetime(2009,04,01)* in a meaningful way.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Since the string is in ISO format, it can be meaningfully compared directly with the ISO format version of the `datetime` you mention:

```
>>> s='2005-08-11T16:34:33Z'
>>> t=datetime.datetime(2009,04,01)
>>> t.isoformat()
'2009-04-01T00:00:00'
>>> s < t
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: can't compare datetime.datetime to str
>>> s < t.isoformat()
True
>>> z='2009-10-01T18:20:12'
>>> z < t.isoformat()
False
```

as you see, while you can't compare string with datetime objects, as long as the strings are in ISO format it's fine to compare them with the `.isoformat()` of the datetime objects. That's the beauty of the ISO format string representation of dates and times: it's correctly comparable and sorts correctly **as strings**, without necessarily requiring conversion into other types.

If you're keen to convert, of course, you can:

```
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime(s, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')
datetime.datetime(2005, 8, 11, 16, 34, 33)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend taking a look at: http://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/parser.html

`from dateutil.parser import parse
datetime = parse("Sat Oct 11 17:13:46 UTC 2003")`

Answer (score 0):

If you know the string just use the datetime.datetime(year, month, day, hour, minute, second) function. Split your string to get the appropriate variables and put it in to make it a datetime type. Then just compare it against whatever you need.

Or you can use the iso format as people have suggested also.

Comment: Thank you Jug. That is how I have been doing it but knew there must be something more elegant out there. And, Alex provided it. :)

Comment: You're welcome! Alex's is definitely the more elegant solution. I wasn't positive of how the iso format worked off the top of my head and am away from my normal computer to check.