# String to Datetime

Tags: python, json, datetime, formatting

I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2721782/convert-date-string-to-datetime-object-in-python) which answered most of my question, however I have a .[dot] at the end of my string:

```
2011-03-09T09:58:28.649615
```

What %[a-z] do I need to use and were can I find more information on this. I know it's related to c.

thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the part after the dot are probably microseconds...

`datetime.datetime.strptime("2011-03-09T09:58:28.649615","%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f")`

reference: [Python documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior)

Comment: So what do I do if I don't want the year, month and the date?