# Creating a web query form

Tags: python, django, forms

I have two models: Director, and Film.

I want to create a web query form so that a user can search something like "All films from director 'Steven Spielberg' between 1990 and 1998".

Just curious what the best and simplest way to do this would be?

Thanks,

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking. Processing a GET request with parameters? Making queries on the database? Both? Something else?

Comment: making queries to a database, i guess they can be the same thing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OK the simplest solution is something like that.

I make some assumptions about the structure of your models, so
adjust accordingly.

Let's say this is our models.py

```
from django.db import models

class Director(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    # maybe some other fields...

class Film(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    director = models.ForeignKey(Director)
    created_at = models.DateField()
```

Our naive views.py
Please keep in mind that I deliberately omit many sanity checks.

```
import datetime
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from myapp.models import Film

def search(request):
    # Suppose we support these params -> ('director', 'fromdate', 'todate')
    request_params = request.GET.copy()
    fromdate = datetime.datetime.strptime(request_params['fromdate'], 'some-string-format')
    todate = datetime.datetime.strptime(request_params['todate'], 'some-string-format')
    # Our query is ready to take off.
    film_results = Film.objects.filter(
        director__name=request_params['director'],
        created_at__range=(fromdate, todate)
    )
    return render_to_response('search_results.html', {'results':film_results})
```

Our search_results.html template

```
{% extends some_base.html %}
{% if results }
  {% for film in results %}
    <h3>{{ film.title }}</h3>
    <p>Director: {{ film.director.name }}</p>
    <p>When: {{ film.created_at }}</p>
  {% endfor %}
{% else %}
  <p>Sorry no results for your query</p>
{% endif %}
```

Also read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2721782/convert-date-string-to-datetime-object-in-python) on creating datetime objects from string

Edit: Oh I forgot about the urls.py and the actual form :)

in your url.py add something like this inside the urlpatterns.

```
url(r'^search/$', 'myapp.views.search'),
```

Now the actual search form must be something like this:

```
<form method='GET', action='/search/'>
... your fields
</form>
```

You can generate it through a django form if you wish.
Anyway this is not going to get you far I guess. If you are doing
anything serious you might take a look into [haystack](http://haystacksearch.org/)

Comment: Hmm, I was hoping I wouldn't have to do all this... what happens if the End-User only selects dates, and no author? will the query just pull all books from like 1990 to 1998?

Comment: Well the things you mention are the sanity checks that I deliberately ommited :)  But how could you automate this? The logic you described can't be inferred without inflexible assumptions. The only thing that needs discussing/thinking is where to put that logic. Inside the view or maybe your search form? You decide.

Answer (score 1):

Hm.  I don't believe any utilty like this exists.  It would be nice if there were a reverse ModelForm.  It would look at field type and get the data ranges for each field for a search form.

I think right now you are stuck with creating a text box and a datepicker range.  And processing that data in a view.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to let your users perform "faceted" searches. [Django Haystack](http://haystacksearch.org/) will let you do that. Their documentation contains information about [faceting](http://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/latest/faceting.html).