# How to convert string to timestamp?

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Convert Date String to DateTime Object in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2721782/convert-date-string-to-datetime-object-in-python)

I have a date string:

```
Mon Oct 15 15:05:00 UTC 2012
```

How to converte this string to timestamp ?

Comment: http://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/parser.html

Answer (score 0):

This should help:

http://docs.python.org/library/time.html#time.strptime